# Python REGEX get category from link url and list of strings

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x, parsing

1) I have a list of string that contains url link like this:

```
url = "https://www.hostname.com/p/aaa/category/1kuwuz-abcd"
```

2) and list of strings containing so many string regex like this:

```
ls = [cat. , jumping.dog, ...]    ## . (any characters can be inserted)
```

1) How could i extracting the category?

2) I want to categorizing each element on the list. (ex: if cat. return "cat", or if jumping.dog return "dog")

What i have done were by searching string manually one by one :

```
re.search(category1, url)
re.search(category2, url)
re.search(category3, url)
```

and so for the 2nd problems, manually i make the list become:

```
ls = ['cat', 'cats', 'jumping-dog', 'jumping dog', ...]
```

Can anybody help me in writing for efficient commands? I am new to regex and any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like what you want is a nested for loop:
    for url in urls:
        for pattern in patterns:
            re.search(pattern, url)

Have you thought about what you want to do if a url matches more than one pattern?

Comment: Any reason you must use Regex? Homeworks?

Comment: @anandsun im actually still confused to read regex pattern like this r'/&q=([^&]*)', so what i am doing was straight re.search the 'category' string one by one

Comment: @mootmoot i don't know about any method but what i know is using regex

Comment: your problem is not clear and has many ways to be done other than regex, for example using string method split, to split by "/" then the category will always have a fixed position in the resulting list in which you can apply process it and group it as you want

Comment: You have no idea of python string manipulation then you want to jump into regex that you are not familiar as well ?  Python string function can easily split the url and give you the last category  `url.split('/)[-1]`.  While regex you must traverse the group. Please spend a few hours on using python than wasting your time understanding complicate regex.